# Python - Cutting the first 5 characters from a string - how to get my new shorter string?

Tags: python, string

I'm very new to Python. I am working on an LCD Raspberry Pi project, displaying strings on an LCD.

I create a string from a command to show a radio track name (line 1 in my code), however this string always starts with 'Name:'. This reads directly from MPD (Music Player Daemon) so nothing I can do about that up front.

As it always starts with the same number of characters, I want to remove '5' characters from the start of this string, and have a new string to play with. Sounds simple to me...but I cannot make this work.

I'm trying:

```
Print station[5:]
```

based on something I found while searching for the answer, but it appears to do nothing.

Here's the main block of my code: (again, the 5th line was intended to work...)

```
f=os.popen("echo 'currentsong' | nc localhost 6600 | grep -e '^Name: '")
  station = ""
  for i in f.readlines():
   station += i
   print station[5:]
   str_pad = " " * 16  
   station = str_pad + station  
   for i in range (0, len(station)):  
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)  
    lcd_text = station[i:(i+16)]
    lcd_string(lcd_text,1)  
    time.sleep(0.3)  
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)  
    lcd_string(str_pad,1)
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("**Playing**",2)
```

This just continues to show the entire line, such as "Name: Pink Flloyd - Money"

If anyone can help, I'll be truly grateful.

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you just print station?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `print station[5:]` you're slicing the string and displaying it, but never saving the result. Remember, in Python, strings are immutable (they don't change). As a result, doing `station[5:]` will simply return a new string that is never saved.

Instead, replace line 5 with `station = station[5:]`. This will overwrite the `station` string with the new version that doesn't start with `Name:`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just printing station[5:] won't do what you want. You need to do:

```
station = station[5:]
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you very much. Will accept this as the answer :D

Comment: You're welcome. Check Juan Catalan's answer too, you can do it in the previous line instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace lines 4 and 5 with:

```
station += i[5:]
print station
```

Comment: Ah this works too, and makes my code even shorter. Thanks a lot Juan :)